# Unhandled exception at 0x00E02BB4 in Pointers.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC

Tags: c++

Here's the code I have written in Visual Studio:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;


class pointer
{
    private:
        int *ptr;
        int **ptr1;
    public:
        int FindSize();
};

int pointer :: FindSize()
{
    ptr1 = &ptr;
    return **ptr1;
}

int main()
{
    pointer point;
    int size = point.FindSize();
    cout << size;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00E02BB4 in Pointers.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC

Comment: `*ptr1`, which is `ptr`,  is not initialized, so you mustn't dereference it.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: You're returning a double pointer instead of a dereferenced pointer in your function `findSize()`.

Comment: @Poriferous _"You're returning a double pointer instead of a dereferenced pointer "_ That's wrong. The function returns a dereferenced double pointer, the problem is that the pointer it points to was never initialized correctly.

Comment: yes *ptr was not initialized with a valid location..thanks

Comment: 0xCC means you've read [uninitialized memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)